# Why AddressEntry.Members is deprecated?. What is the alternate method for the same?

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am working an Outlook addin in C# recently. For several times I meet "internal error" exception when calling AddressEntry.Members property. (AddressEntry is the class in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace)

I searched the web but only found that the property is deprecated according to MSDN, but neither the reason nor the replacement are mentioned. Any information about that is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is still very much alive and well. It is the only way to access members of a distribution list.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the prompt reply! It is sad to hear this is the only way to access members of a distribution list, because it sometimes throws frustrating "internal support error". Is there anyway to work around this error? Will retry work? Or reduce the number of members in the distribution list?